# UPDATE and MIN SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Im tring to update the MIN value of a column, but cant seem to make my syntax work.
I keep getting the error
 *#1093 - You can't specify target table 'turcare_turutstyr' for update in FROM clause*

My query is

```
UPDATE tableName
SET solgt = true
WHERE produktid = (SELECT min(produktid) FROM tableName
               WHERE artnr = '1234'
               AND solgt = false)
```

Where am i doing it wrong?

Comment: `UPDATE tableName
SET solgt = true
WHERE produktid IN 
(
   select * from
   (
     SELECT min(produktid) FROM tableName
     WHERE artnr = '1234'
     AND solgt = false
   ) TMP
)`

Comment: Is "tableName" `turcare_turutstyr`? Is it actually a view?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I cant believe I have been going around it the wrong way..

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not allow you to directly use the same table twice in an `update` or `delete` query.  Well, it does.  One method uses `join`:

```
UPDATE tableName t JOIN
       (SELECT min(produktid) as produktid
        FROM tableName
        WHERE artnr = '1234' AND solgt = false
      ) tt
      ON t.produktid = tt.produktid
    SET solgt = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

May be your where clause return more than 1 row

```
 UPDATE tableName
    SET solgt = true
    WHERE produktid in (SELECT min(produktid) FROM tableName
                   WHERE artnr = '1234'
                   AND solgt = false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  [juergen d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575376/juergen-d) ive solved it

```
UPDATE turcare_turutstyr 
SET solgt = true 
WHERE produktid IN ( select * from ( SELECT min(produktid) 
                                FROM turcare_turutstyr 
                                WHERE artnr = '1234' 
                                AND solgt = false ) 
                TMP )
```